# Generating combinations in a list but only in ascending order

Tags: python-2.7, python-itertools

I got a list,

```
a=['z','g','b','h']
```

Now when I do,

```
for p in itertools.permutations(a,2):print p
```

I get,

```
('z', 'g')
('z', 'b')
('z', 'h')
('g', 'z')
('g', 'b')
('g', 'h')
('b', 'z')
('b', 'g')
('b', 'h')
('h', 'z')
('h', 'g')
('h', 'b')
```

I only need these combinations,

```
('z', 'g')
('z', 'b')
('z', 'h')
('g', 'b')
('g', 'h')
('b', 'h')
```

And do not need following. Which are in reverse order,

```
('g', 'z')
('b', 'z')
('b', 'g')
('h', 'z')
('h', 'g')
('h', 'b')
```

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Late but found it myself :-)

Just use combinations instead of permutations.

```
for p in itertools.combinations(a,2):print p


Out[1]:
('z', 'g')
('z', 'b')
('z', 'h')
('g', 'b')
('g', 'h')
('b', 'h')
```